# widgets in contacts only

Tags: widgets, contact

I have a few pages listed in my top menu. these are: contacts, My account and messages. I have added a map to the "Pages Sidebar" tab in admin. But it seems to add the map to all 3 pages listed above but I only want it to appear on the contact page and not the other 2 as in the other 2 I would like something else (an advert to memberships maybe).

How can I do this?

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

there are many plugins for that, try this one, its pretty easy:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-context/

or if you dont want to use a plugin, add a new sidebar to the specific page u desire:
http://www.blogohblog.com/adding-extra-sidebar-to-your-wordpress-theme/

Comment: Link one is great but it will not let me elect just one page (contact) and typing "contact" in to the "or target by URL" section does not work either. Any Ideas?

Comment: Link 2 sounds rather good but it does not show the codes that I need to post in to the sidebar2.php pages in my child theme. Please Help.

Comment: anyone got any more ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

"Target by url" works if you change the Widget-context drop-down before it to "Show on Selected"
try